# Repair .NET 3.5 Framework - Domain Controller

Tags: windows-server-2008, domain-controller, .net

Server manager says that .NET Framework 3.5 is installed. When I try to install an application that needs .NET Framework 3.5 can't be installed because they are saying that it's not available.

Is it possible to repair/reinstall .NET Framework 3.5 on a Domain Controller?

Answer (score 1):

> When I try to install an application that needs .NET Framework 3.5 can't be installed 
>   because they are saying that it's not available.

Says who? The installer?

In this case you need to contact whoever made it and have them fix their installer. Installers are notoriously one thing people put in not too smart conditions without thinking. It is possible for example they do a version check for 3.5 and you have a slightly newer version due to fixes - and the installer is hardcoded because hey, in their world noone ever release a patch (or in this case service packs).

If the installer is a MSI file you could try hacking it in the precondition secion - otherwise you are out of luck.

Comment: The Installer, indeed. It was the Dirsync tool from Microsoft, to sync Office 365 with Active Directory.

Installing .NET Framework 4.5 fixed this issue, but I'm worried for problems in the future..

Comment: Ok, that makes it funny because intersting enougn MS is quite good with their installers and office 365 is current (i.e. not some years old tool). Did you patch up the server properly?

Comment: Yeah, Server is patched 100%. But it's also giving me errors with the DirSync installation, so the Windows installation is probably corrupt.

Comment: Access to some VM's? As in: put up another machine, isntall a separate AD - takes 10 minutes - and check there. If it is a corrupt install, that will validate it is one.

Answer (score -1):

Try http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30135 "Microsoft .NET Framework Repair Tool"